# Mouseover triggering underlaying sibling?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have two sibling `divs`. One div is a sub-navigation that partially overlays the slider div. I have a `mouseover` event on the slider, which hides the sub-navigation.

The problem is, as soon as I mouse over the sub-navigation, the slider `mouseover` event is triggered even though my mouse isn't touching the slider yet - although the mouse is technically over the slider - it's just being overlayed by the sub-navigation.

Hopefully I explained this well that someone will understand. Is there any way around this issue?

Comment: So you want the second div (sibling) to be hidden when the group is hovered over?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example replicating your issue? Probably, meanwhile, you could also try preventing `Event Propagation` if using `jQuery`. If your sub-navigation is a child of the slider div, the mouseover event is probably propagating to the parent navigation in the DOM.

Comment: They are siblings, so event propagation isn't an issue from what I understand. I've also assigned appropriate z-index to each of them (No idea if that does anything, really).

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle

Comment: I've figured out the issue while creating the jsFiddle. I had to `float` the sub-navigation for it to work properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to hide the second sibling, this will work. Just replace the css class names (`subNav`, `slider`) with whatever they actually are. Also, instead of `left:100px` do whatever you wanted to do here to the second div.

```
div.subNav:hover + div.slider {
   left: 100px;
}
```

The plus sign (+) is a "adjacent sibling selector" in css.

Comment: When I mouseover the slider, I want the sub-navigation to be removed. Although, because the sub-navigation overlays the slider, whenever I mouseover the sub-navigation, the slider mouseover event is triggered. Which I don't want.